# Сортировка options в select на js

Tags: javascript

```
function loadsterjq(data) {

   data = JSON.parse(data);
    var out = '<select style="width: 210px;">';
    out += '<option data-id="">Выбрать:</option>';
    for (var id in data) {
        out +=`<option data-id="${id}">${data[id].diametr} x ${data[id].dlina}</option>`;
    }
    out +='</select>';

}
```

При запуске сортирует по id, а мне надо по data[id].diametr. Как можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
    const massiv = [];
    for (var q in data) {
        massiv.push(data[q]);
    }
    massiv.sort(function(a, b){return a.thickness - b.thickness;});
    var out = '<select>';
    out += '<option data-id="">Выберите:</option>';
    for (var id in massiv) {
        out +=`<option data-id="${id}">${massiv[id].thickness} x (${massiv[id].dimensions})</option>`;
    }
    out +='</select>';
```

После чего все корректно сортируется

Comment: Это хорошо. Только значения `data-id="${id}"` будут другие.

Answer (score 1):

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.diametr - b.diametr);
for (var id in data) {
    out +=`<option data-id="${id}">${data[id].diametr} x ${data[id].dlina}</option>`;
}
```

Comment: Ругается на sort: Uncaught TypeError: data.sort is not a function
    at Object.loadsterjq [as success] (functionsterj.js:30)

Comment: @АндрейПанов Вы понимаете, что я понятия не имею, что представляет собой `data`?

Comment: $books = R::getAssoc("SELECT * FROM sterj ORDER BY diametr ASC");
 if ((R::count('sterj')) > 0){
     echo json_encode($books);
 }
Передаю данные из БД

Comment: @АндрейПанов `console.log(data);` - ?

Comment: Это обьекты:
{1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}}
1: {diametr: "30", dlina: "1000", ves: "0,8", price: "285"}
2: {diametr: "40", dlina: "200", ves: "0,3", price: "286"}
3: {diametr: "40", dlina: "1000", ves: "1,6", price: ""}
4: {diametr: "50", dlina: "1000", ves: "2,5", price: ""}
5: {diametr: "63", dlina: "1000", ves: "4,4", price: ""}
6: {diametr: "70", dlina: "850", ves: "3,8", price: ""}
7: {diametr: "70", dlina: "1000", ves: "4,6", price: ""}
8: {diametr: "80", dlina: "850", ves: "5,0", price: ""}